# Is it possible to resume the state of a certain widget page in flutter after popping the page out?

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies

Let's say for example when I press on the Like button (from the Like_button package) it will set its boolean to true, meaning that it will turn red. But when I pop this page out of the navigation and go back to it, how do I get it to show that I have previously pressed the button already? (right now what it does is it shows the same state as if i didn't press on it before) I want to make it into like 'favourite article' system.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:like_button/like_button.dart';

class Article extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _ArticleState createState() => _ArticleState();
}

class _ArticleState extends State<Article> {
bool isLiked = false;

 @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.green[50],
        body: SingleChildScrollView(
           GestureDetector(
              onTap: () {
                  Navigator.pushNamed(context, '/N1');
                  },
              child: Container(
              margin: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical:10),
              child: Padding(
                padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(30, 0, 30, 0),
                child: Card(
                  shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(25.0)),
                  child: Column(
                        children: [
                          Stack(
                            children: [
                              ClipRRect(
                                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(25.0),
                                child: Image.asset('assets/CoverImage1.jpeg')),
                              Positioned(
                                top: 15,
                                right: 15,
                                child: Container(
                                  width:50,
                                  height:50,
                                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                    color: Colors.white,
                                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(15.0)),
                                    border: Border.all(color: Color.fromRGBO(141, 141, 141, 1.0).withAlpha(40)),
                                  ),
                                  child: Center(
                                    child: LikeButton(
                                      size: 25,
                                      isLiked: isLiked,
                                      likeBuilder: (isLiked) {
                                        final color = isLiked ? Colors.red : Colors.grey;
                                        return Icon(Icons.favorite, color:color, size:25);
                                      },
                                      onTap: (isLiked) async {
                                        this.isLiked = !isLiked;
                                        return !isLiked;
                                      }
                                    ),
                                  ),
                              ), 
                              ),
                            ],
                          ),
```

Comment: Use a global variable for saving the state. Currently, you have it inside the class so every time a new screen is drawn the variable is being set to default true value.

Comment: could i get an example code for that?

Answer (score 0):

you can store the value of variable with shared preferences.

you can check the documentation here: https://pub.dev/packages/shared_preferences/example

try these steps:

1. store value with something like prefs.setBool()
2. get the value with getBool in initState(). initState() always perform before UI widget is built.

with these steps enables the app to get the value even when apps is closed

Comment: could you provide some example code with the code i provided on top? I have no idea how to use shared_preferences package :(